# Siamese networks Accuracy?

Tags: conv-neural-network, loss-function

I'm using the contrastive loss layer from this paper:

I've set the margin to a certain value. But I am not quite sure
how I would calculate the accuracy for a classification task.

As far as I know, I would calculate the euclidean distance from the features and check for a certain threshold. Would this threshold be the same one as the margin? Or is this another parameter which has to be found?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this? I'm also going through the same problem